# Quasar build failing

Tags: vite, quasar-framework, quasar

I am using Quasar with Vite. My app is served fine in the dev environment, but when I run `quasar build`, I get this error:

> App •  WAIT  • Compiling of SPA UI with Vite in progress...
> Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are
> not JavaScript) file:
> C:/Users/b_kog/Projects/Ofanym/OfanymFrontend/node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.mjs:1153:21
> 1151:     } 1152:     function addCharToBuffer() { 1153:
> buffer += char;
> ^ 1154:     } 1155:     while (i < path.length) {
> C:\Users\b_kog\Projects\Ofanym\OfanymFrontend\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:198
> base = Object.assign(new Error(base.message), base);
> ^

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I created a new project and copied everything over into it. Quasar build now works. No idea what the issue was. [image]